# Control setup for a command oriented interface?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a customizable control setting stored for each user in the database.
Now I am loading the the control settings and the look like this:

```
some possible user input (eg. ctrl + s) => some command (eg. save file)
```

Now I have a hash/dictionary that is generated in runtime based on the info from the database.

The hash has a `key` which is the users' input and a `value` which is needed to activate the command.

Since this is a command oriented interface, the value needs to allow me to instantiate a new command object, for instance, the value could be a factory.

The issue is that I am discouraged by the concept of have having one factory for each command as it sounds a bit overkill since there are many dozens of commands.

I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to set up  a command oriented interface.

I am using Haxe but it's a general oop / design patterns question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register your commands with your command processor and then the processor would ask each command in turn to respond to the input. If the command responds, the processor work is done; if not, it asks the next command in the [chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Alternatively, for simple matching of a string input with a command, the processor could keep a map (or hashtable) of the string inputs to the commands instances.

This all presupposes that your commands are already instantiated and part of a collection kept by the processor, so they should also be reusable between invocations.